# Using the WF rules engine without workflow in production - implementation experiences

Tags: .net, workflow, business-logic, rule-engine

I'm designing an application for a type of case management system that has a big requirement for customizable, flexible business rules. I'm planning on using the WF Rules Engine without workflow (see: [here](http://www.joshlane.net/blog/WindowsWorkflowRulesEngineWithoutWindowsWorkflow.aspx), among other examples and such).

One of the points my client brought up (justifiably so!) is whether there are extant examples of using the rules engine for a business rules engine without workflow.

My question, of course is: Has anyone used the WF Rules engine sans workflow in a production application before, and what were your experiences?

Answer (score 2):

The WF3 rules engine is still available in .NET 4.

There are available [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483375(v=VS.100).aspx) showing how to use the WF3 rules engine with WF4, as well as [migration guidance](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wf4migration) that is specific to rules.

Answer (score 2):

Josh,
   Do you have any example code to assist with this effort? I have some code stubbed out based on the ExternalRuleSetTool for adding/editing rule sets and I found some code here - http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/08/how-to-use-windows-workflow-rules.html that covers a lot of how to get this to work even though there sample links are broken. At any rate, what I don't see is how to return the results of RuleSet.Execute(). Obviously, providing user feedback about what went wrong while executing the rules is important. I'm sure that I am just missing something trivial but I have never worked with WF before so this is all new to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know this is a long time to wait for a response, but I'll look into writing up a sample for a blog post soon

Comment: RuleSet.Execute [returns void](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.rules.ruleset.execute(v=vs.110).aspx). The "results" of your rules should be actions taken by the rules. If something goes wrong, RuleSet.Execute may throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The old WF3 rules engine I believe no longer exists in .net 4 WF. I could be wrong but we dropped using it more than ago. You need to check with MS to see if its supported going forwards I'd suggest.

However according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960221(VS.100).aspx) the new rules engine seems to be very similar - so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: where did you hear this? That's definitely news to me... why would MS want to drop WWF?

Comment: Sorry rephrased. I never said WF was being dropped.

Comment: The article you linked to is the same one I've used as part of my research - the external rule set toolkit works very well and is a good starting point! The article is written against .NET 3.0 / VS 2005, FYI

Comment: Preet - why did your org drop using the Rules Engine? We've found that it's absurdly easy to implement a dynamic business rules engine without workflows with it... it almost seems TOO easy, ya know?

Comment: We stopped using it, as we went on to use IronPython and now the DLR. This gave us much more flexibility. However we are major users of WF so our use case was very different than your. Business rules are trivial to implement in a dynamic language like that.